# Samsung S3: avoid automatic screen lock

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-3

My Samsung Galaxy S3 automatically locks the screen after a given number of minutes. After this I have to insert a secret code to unlock. I can disable this feature, checking "Never lock screen". In this way screen will never lock (and this is ok) but as side effect it will never turn to black (this isn't ok, this will drain my battery).

I want that screen just to turn to black without locking, in this way as soon screen is touched phone is immediately active.

If I click the side power button phone will go in locked mode as usual (secret code is needed to unlock).

I've found some application that partially do this. In some case I have to click on the main button to reactivate phone, while I want that entire screen as sensible zone.

What can I do?

Comment: To save battery, screen needs to be turned off. If it projects black image, it'll drain battery. And, wake up by touch isn't possible if screen is turned off.

Comment: Which **Android** version?  (in case relevant)

Comment: @Sachin: You could post that as possible solution / explanation.

Comment: @david6 Version 4.0.4.

Comment: @SachinShekhar this sounds reasonable. But i'm still asking why. My old Nokia 5800 turnsoff the screen and wakeup only with a touch on it.

Comment: With some types of 'touch' technology, there could be hardware support to 'wake-up' on any activity.  But this would be susceptible to false triggers (wake-up in pocket, etc.)  Many of the 1st/2nd generation smart phones did this.  And their battery life was v. poor.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the passcode feature? Then you can still save battery life by locking the screen, but then it is also very easy to get back into your phone with the swipe of a finger or whatever else you would like depending on your ROM.